# Installing with pip through xargs

Tags: pip, xargs

I am trying to do some filtering on requirement.txt before installing individual python packages with pip (v3). I am stumped though why my usage of xargs here is messing up the pip command:

```
cat ./requirements.txt | xargs -I XXX pip --no-deps install XXX

...
Usage:
  pip <command> [options]

no such option: --no-deps
...
```

If I just run `pip --no-deps install SOMEPACKAGE` then it works no problem. What's going on here please, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You should write `pip install --no-deps` instead of `pip --no-deps install` as `--no-deps` is an option of `install` and not viceversa.

Comment: Blush. Thanks. Will delete question.

Comment: Errare humanum est ^_^